# facebook like notifications with tornado, mongodb

Tags: mongodb, notifications, tornado, pymongo

I have an app that has facebook login. The users have an action which affects other users. I'd like the affected users to be notified in real time, if they are logged in, otherwise they should see the notifications the next time they login. I'm using `tornado`(non-blocking) on the server side. The database is `mongodb`. I'm using `motor` as my async mongodb client and I think I'd like to use `socket.io`. So far, This is how I think I should do it:

1. Whenever a user say `user1` performs an action that affects `user2`, the row corresponding to `user2` in the `users` collection will get updated in some way that is sufficient to produce the notification content.
2. When a user say `user2` logs into the website, it connects via `socket.io` to a websocket. On the server side, inside `on_connect` all the stored notifications are sent to the client and a handler is installed that monitors the row corresponding to `user2` in the `users` collection. Whenever it detects a change, it'll send out a message indicating a new notification. Also, on reading a notification, the client will send a message to the server which will reset the entry in the `users` collection. These handlers have to be de-registered on disconnect.

The questions is, how to install these handlers? I can't find any way to get mongodb to notify me of any change. How do I do this?

Comment: Mongodb doesn't have any standard way of providing change notifications. You'd need to add that to your data layer code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably mongo-watch is what you need

Here is github repo

https://github.com/TorchlightSoftware/mongo-watch